# testrun of form in visual studio c# shows a visible small scale version of it

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

i recently installed visual studio 2015 and made my first code in c#.
('maximized' for window state at the properties of the form)
everything went fine (comilation and testrun without errors) until i attempted to load one of the example tutorials, which i interrupted during loading.
after that i compiled and started my self coded application again from within visual studio. this time the output of the form was, unlike before, displayed half its size.
all the buttons including the window of the form appeared half its original size.
but when i executed the comiled application outside of visual studio (without it actually running) the application started in normal scale as intended.

this effect happens for this specific project only. if i start a new project the compilation & testrun will show a form scale as expected.

so my question: is there any magical setting that i have to change to end this nightmare ? i dont like to start all over again with a new project. i had set up 72 different button already. each buttonpress causes a different 
SendKeys.Send("");
to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Form's [`AutoScaleMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property!

The default is `Font`:

> Controls scale relative to the dimensions of the font the classes are
>   using, which is typically the system font.

If that won't help do try to create a new project and copy the relevant cs-files into it!

In [theory](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/) there is a zoom option in the VS designer, but at least in the Winforms desiner the shortcut does nothing for me.. It probably is for the WPF designer.

You did tag the question correctly and it is indeed about Winforms?

Comment: thank you for your answer.
yes, it is indeed about a winform. i chosed a winform as a new project when i started it.
 i tried both options your described to me. the last one caused several errors which i felt unable to deal with (im new to visual studio and c#). but none of the options worked.
now i changed the settings in debugging/properties of <name of the project>
usually the setting is 'start project'. i changed it now to: 'start external program' (that external program is the executable which is created by visual studio)

what an awkward fix of mine !